# Database design, variable number of columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have a simple application in which users submit data into a table.

There are currently 3 fields the user can pass values to at the moment. I'm trying to find a solution where the number of description columns can vary, depending on the description list created by the user.

So far I have considered:

1. having the user_input table have many nullable description
   fields, say from 1-15 and thus limiting the number of description
   fields the user can define to 15. This solution is very easy to
   query and maintain, however is limited to a set number of fields.
   (is this a viable and acceptable solution in general?)
2. creating a table where each row would correspond to 1 description
   entered. This would allow the user to create unlimited number of
   description fields, however storing each all inputs would instead of
   1 row now take n-rows, where n is the count of descriptions linked
   to the current description_list. Users are free to choose the amount
   of columns, however not so easy to query and maintain.

My current table is something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_input` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`description_list_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`description1` int(11) NOT NULL,
`description2` int(11) NOT NULL,
`description3` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Are there any other solutions?

Comment: What's `description_list_id` and why are the description columns integers?

Comment: Also note that you will be wasting 14 bytes (or 28 bytes if VARCHAR length > 28) per row if you use option #1, assuming most users only use one description. This can be pretty expensive if you go for more columns.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Definitely option #2.  Normalizaing is always the best option in a scenario like this.  You are correct that it is more work, but you are overcoming the inevitable issue when you will need more than 15 descriptions.

Comment: Assuming that your description_list_id is a foreing key to some table named "description_list", then what you are describing is basically a N-to-N relationship between tables users and description_lists, with attached data (the description field).

And note that this is probably easier to query. Think for example how you would query youor database to find "how much users answered description = 12 for description_list_id = 3". You will end up with an awful WHERE clause, looking something as: "description1 = 12 OR description2 = 12 OR ...".  Solution #2 make extracting summaries much easier.

Comment: description_list_id is a foreign key however it stores the values that are shown to user when they view the data they have submitted(in order to not display 'description1').

Comment: OK, say I go with option 2. How should one go about retrieving the data? Is there a way to retrieve what used to be 1 row in the db in one query with solution nr 2?

Comment: You **could** denormalize the data in the query: `select case when desc_seq_id = 1 then desc.desc_text end as desc1,case when desc_seq_id = 2 then desc.desc_text end...`, but you'd be better off retrieving the multiple rows as an ordered list, and then iterating through the rows in your front-end application.  Or take the God-awful approach described [here](http://http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Dont-Be-Evil.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

The second solution is preferable in terms of flexibility. If tomorrow you need to add more description fields with the first solution you will need to modify the table and the code to manage it.

The second solution can require a bit more work now but then it will handle 2 like 200 descriptions.

The first approach is more a quick and dirty solution for a small problem, the second also a good exercise if you have time to try something new.

Answer (score 0):

another option:
You can have descriptions column with type as string. In this save | delimited description.

If there is use case to differentiate between different descriptions like one user can save value for description 4,7 then add one more column which save the column header.

Limitation : you wont be able to query on description directly but it can be handled on application side.
I would suggest to use this if data is changes less frequently and query is not based on description.